# Javascript counting the letters inputed in email instead of outputting the email itself

Tags: javascript, html

I'm stuck on trying to get the email outputted instead of numbers related to the amount of words inputed

`var output2 = "Email: " + at;` is counting the amount of letters that was inputed.

I'm trying to figure out how its counting the amount of letters and why is it not outputting the email instead

#### Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
function myFunction() {
  var uname = document.getElementById("uname").value;
  var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  var at = document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf("@");
  submitOk = "true";


  if (uname.length > 16) {
    alert("Characters have exceeded specified amount");
    submitOk = "false";
  }

  if (age < 13 || age > 19) {
    alert("Numbers must be between 13 and 19");
    submitOk = "false";
  }

  if (at == -1) {
    alert("not a valid E-mail");
  }

  if (submitOk == "false") {}

  if (submitOk == "true") {}

  var output = "Name: " + uname;
  var output1 = "Age: " + age;
  var output2 = "Email: " + at;

  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
  document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = output1;
  document.getElementById("output2").innerHTML = output2;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return myFunction()">
  Name : <br><input type="text" id="uname" size="30" placeholder="Maximum of 16 Characters"><br> Age : <br><input type="number" id="age" size="30" placeholder="From 13 to 19 only"><br> E-mail : <br><input type="text" id="email" size="30" placeholder="Examplename@mail.com"><br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction();return false" value="Submit">
</form>

<table class="center">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="output"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="output1"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="output2"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Probably because you have `.indexOf("@")` when you are declaring `var at`.

Comment: what would be the fix for this?

Comment: The fix depends on what your purpose is.  Are you trying to count the letters before the @ sign?  Are you trying to count the letters for the entire email?  After the @ sign?

Comment: im not trying to count any of the letters im trying to get the email to display at the last part. This issue was fixed for my by using for loop instead im trying to help for a friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `at` is being used to verify that the email has an `@` symbol, not neccessarily return the pure value as seen here where it's calculated:

```js
var at = document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf("@");
```

`indexOf("@")` will return the position of the first at symbol if found, or `-1` if not found.

If you just want the email address, you can break into two statements:

```js
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var at = email.indexOf("@");
```